# Thunderbird 3 - missing feature: Show folder size

Tags: thunderbird

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thunderbird 3: see size of folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/88952/thunderbird-3-see-size-of-folder)

In TB2 I was able to see the size of the folders (for example Inbox, Junk, Trash). 
That was useful because it showed to me large folders so I can clean/tidy them.

However in TB3, I cannot find a setting from where I can put this back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Extra Folder Columns](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/9716/) It allows you view the size of your email folders and the number of unread emails in each folder.

Comment: I don't like at all installing beta plugins but I need that feature badly. +1. Thanks.